# Ember js import a UMD node module

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, umd

I have to import this library and have the "ZeroEx" variable global across all ember files.

i tried to add this line in *ember-cli-build.js* but I got **no such file or directory**

```
app.import('node_modules/0x.js');
```

https://0xproject.com/docs/0x.js#installation

Answer (score 1):

There is a new ember add-on that should make this easy for you: `ember-auto-import` https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import